# how to send the (array of elements) output of one query to another query

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT SUM(Marks) AS tot
FROM [Tbl_Results]
WHERE [month] = 'Mar'
    AND [year] = '2016'
GROUP BY sname
```

the output of the above query i want to pass to the another query stating that max of the "Marks"

```
select MAX(?)  from [Tbl_Results]  
? how to pass an argument to get an max of marks from the table
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.
You can create a [cte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) from your first query, like this:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT SUM(Marks) AS tot
    FROM [Tbl_Results]
    WHERE [month] = 'Mar'
    AND [year] = '2016'
    GROUP BY sname
)

SELECT MAX(tot)  
FROM cte
```

Or you could create a view from it:

```
CREATE VIEW vwTot 
AS

    SELECT SUM(Marks) AS tot
    FROM [Tbl_Results]
    WHERE [month] = 'Mar'
    AND [year] = '2016'
    GROUP BY sname
GO

SELECT MAX(tot)  
FROM vwTot
```

You can also insert the results into a temporary table:

```
SELECT SUM(Marks) AS tot INTO #Temp
FROM [Tbl_Results]
WHERE [month] = 'Mar'
AND [year] = '2016'
GROUP BY sname

SELECT MAX(tot)  
FROM #Temp
```

Or use it as a derived table:

```
SELECT MAX(tot)  
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(Marks) AS tot
    FROM [Tbl_Results]
    WHERE [month] = 'Mar'
    AND [year] = '2016'
    GROUP BY sname
) dt
```

Comment: tq , with dis i want select sname also along with the max of marks, "select sname, MAX(tot) from ( SELECT sname, SUM(Marks) AS tot FROM [Tbl_Results] WHERE [month] = 'Mar' AND [year] = '2016' GROUP BY sname ) b" shall i use like dis

Comment: Input to this: the best way to optimize performance for this is to use the temporary table method, putting clustered index on the `tot` column.

Comment: @tobypls I'm not so sure that's correct. a temporary table will have it's own overhead and indexes might be useful or not depending on the size of the data. I'm also not sure that indexing will help the sum aggregation to work faster.

Comment: @Vinay Please avoid using comments to write code, it's almost unreadable. instead, edit your question to include the new code.

Comment: @ZoharPeled You're right, depending on the number of rows this might not be the best thing since the total overhead could become greater than without an index. However, selecting the `MAX` on an indexed column should be more efficient in any case, am I right?

Comment: @tobypls probably. I currently don't have the time to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with an older style and  `select` your first set of results into a temp table.  This can be helpful if you need to perform other operations on that intermediate set of results.  For example:

```
SELECT SUM(Marks) AS tot
INTO #results
FROM [Tbl_Results]
WHERE [month] = 'Mar'
    AND [year] = '2016'
GROUP BY sname

SELECT MAX(tot)
FROM #results

DROP TABLE #results
```

Or, you can go with a more up-to-date style and use a [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to achieve your result in a single query:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUM(Marks) AS tot
    FROM [Tbl_Results]
    WHERE [month] = 'Mar'
        AND [year] = '2016'
    GROUP BY sname)
SELECT MAX(tot)
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a subquery. since you're using a groupby clause you also need to add sname to your select statement.

```
select MAX(tot)  from 
(
    SELECT  sname, SUM(Marks) AS tot
    FROM [Tbl_Results]
    WHERE [month] = 'Mar'
    AND [year] = '2016'
    GROUP BY sname
) b
```

Comment: tq , with dis i want select sname also along with the max of marks,  "select sname, MAX(tot) from ( SELECT sname, SUM(Marks) AS tot FROM [Tbl_Results] WHERE [month] = 'Mar' AND [year] = '2016' GROUP BY sname ) b" shall i use like dis

Comment: select sname, max(tot) from (...) where max(tot) = (select max(tot) from [table]) group by sname